# Java 8 Enum Defenition use 'new' as enum value

Tags: java

I wanna use the 'new' keyword as one of values in Enum is there anyway? Now I'm facing syntax error.

```
public enum StatusEnum {
    new ,done
}
```

Comment: If you just follow the naming convention for enum values, the problem goes away. Use `NEW`, `DONE`. You can't use a keyword as an identifier anywhere.

Comment: @ernest_k The problem is that i have this in my db and I have records stored this way with new value as String and now i want to change my saving business and i've got 6 status states which new is one of them

Comment: In this case you have to migrate your data by a sql update.

Comment: @Jens There is a way to have custom Name with different value in java in enum. as They said in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  new is a reserved keyword.  It has a specific meaning in Java, and cannot be used as a name.  You could use New and Done, or NEW and DONE.

Comment: Convention to use `NEW` and `DONE`.

Comment: @James Conventions mean nothing.  Use whatever you like.  Personally I find the all caps style ugly and hard on the eyes.

Comment: @GabeSechan Conventions mean nothing? That's an interesting point of view. The OP wouldn't have this problem if they followed related conventions.

Comment: @ernest_k Because they don't.  There's zero actual value in doing it one way vs the other.  His problem was he didn't know a basic programming rule-  that you can't use a keyword as a name.  He could have had the exact same problem if he followed conventions but used new as a variable name.

Comment: Well, you've got a point, although "mean nothing" is just too radical. And as something to teach new learners, it's to discourage, IMHO.

Comment: @ernest_k I go the exact opposite way.  Pointless style conventions are not only not worth enforcing, they will in their career read a LOT of code that doesn't follow it.  So its best not to teach them "it must be done like this" if it doesn't have to be done like this.  The times to enforce things is where there are potential correctness and performance impacts (for example, always put {} around if statements because editing it will happen and people forget to add them in).  Not when its meaningless things like capitalization or spacing.  It provides no value other than pure pedantry.

Comment: @GabeSechan The problem is that i have this in my db and I have records stored this way with new value as String and now i want to change my saving business and i've got 6 status states which new is one of them

Comment: @arashyousefi You can set the value of the enum to "new" without calling it new.  Simply declare it NEW("new").  The variable would be named NEW, but it would have the value "new"

Comment: @GabeSechan -  I see. At least it's not that binary, there are shades of gray. But I hope that doesn't include letting your team of juniors write `new_, nEW, doNE, donE, doNE` (in the same enum or not, just because it's legal syntax) :)